# Toogle breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an asp.net core mvc project in Visual Studio 2019.
I have seen others discussing this issue and have done the following:

Debug mode is set to debug, not release.
Deleted the bin and obj folders.
Cleaned and rebuilded the solution.
Deleted all breakpoints.

None of this have worked. What else is there to do?

Comment: Does this happen with any new project? So if you create a new project, hit F5 and set a breakpoint, this occurs? Sometimes assembly loading can take some time though, so it could just take a moment for it to show up normally.

Comment: Yes. It happens in every new project I create. Also, no matter how much I wait for it to load, it doesnt become normal.

Comment: Uhh that's really odd :\

Comment: Is your project running under IIS Express or IIS ?

Comment: It is IIS Express

Comment: @Natasha Drost, Whether the break point staying red or not? Have you get any warning message?

Comment: Maybe you could check here to find solution [Troubleshoot Breakpoints in the Visual Studio Debugger]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2019

Comment: @MichelleWang, Its not staying red. Also the breakpoints are in the javascript code, which is also not working, but works in an online editor.

Comment: It doesnt seem that the error I have is being discussed in the article. But thanks anway.

Comment: Ok, that's why not working. Visual Studio .NET debugger doesn't stop on breakpoints when you debug ASP.NET pages.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/debugger-not-stop-breakpoint

Comment: If you want to debug javascript code, you could try Debug(F12) in broswer.

Comment: @MichelleWang debugging in the browser was the life-savior of today. Apparently there was an error I'd missed and when I removed that it works perfectly now.

Comment: So glad you solved.   :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `JavaScript` debug, I suggest you could try using browser debug tool(F12).It is more flexible.

**Debugging js**

1. Press `F12` to open Dev tools control panel.
2. Open `Source` Tab and select the file where you code is from directory.
3. Add `Breakpoint` to the line you need to debug.
4. Press `F5` to refresh your page.

[image]

Comment: If the source tab is blank (step 2), refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to debug JavaScript is in browsers Dev Tool, one way of doing it is directly opening the Dev tool and placing the debugger on the line of code you want to debug , answer by Michelle Wang explains that.

But at times it can become hard to find the file and code in Dev Tool, so to make your life easy you can follow the below approach

1. add the debugger to your code,

   [image: function myFunction(a, b) { debugger; return a * b; }]
2. run your application, hit F12 to open Dev Tool.
3. And do the required operation that would invoke the line of code you want to debug.
4. that should hit the break point.
5. if you are expecting break point to be hit as soon as you launch application then please have the Dev Tool open and refresh your page.